# Play MP3 files on website in Mobile Safari / iOS8?

Tags: html, ios8, mp3, mobile-safari

MP3 files stopped working in Mobile Safari in iOS 8 (8.0.2 as of today). They won't play when I link directly to them. They won't play when I put them in proper HTML5-compliant audio tags.

Both used to work with iOS 7. (Autoplay doesn't but that's by design.)

Any recommendations for a workaround?